# Input validation python 2.7.13

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to validate input that is going into a list. The input needs to be an integer. How I have it works if I input an integer or a single letter. but if I enter something like 'qw' the program crashes. What can I do to better validate the input? Here is my code:

```
def getPints(pints):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 7:
        pints[counter] = raw_input("Enter the number of pints donated: ")
        check = isinstance(pints[counter], int)
        while check == False:
            print "Please enter an integer!"
            pints[counter] = input("Enter the number of pints donated: ")
        counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, `check` will always evaluate to `False`, because `raw_input()` only returns a string, never an integer. Then you'll get stuck in an infinite `while` loop, because you don't update `check` in it.

Instead of `isinstance`, use the string [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method.

```
check = pints[counter].isdigit()
```

You'll also need to re-evaluate `check` inside the loop. But really, you don't need `check` at all.

```
pints[counter] = raw_input("Enter the number of pints donated: ")
while not pints[counter].isdigit():
    print "Please enter an integer!"
    pints[counter] = raw_input("Enter the number of pints donated: ")
```

I suspect you also want to convert `pints[counter]` to an int once you have a suitable input.

You're using the LBYL method (Look Before You Leap). You can also use the EAFP (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission) method by just trying to convert the input to an int and catching the exception if the input is bad:

```
while True:
    try:
        pints[counter] = int(raw_input("Enter the number of pints donated: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter an integer!"
```